# Datatables CSS/Jquery scripts not modifying my tables

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL575.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXvXf.png)i am new to MVC. i am trying to modify a table using DataTables JQuery scripts. i was able to install the datatable package from NPM. i modified my my bundles in App_Start; i also modified my Layout.cshtml file to be in sync with the budles in my App_Start folder.
thing is, when i modify my table to render using Datable lib, it doesnt. the page still renders the old non formatted table. can any body help me with any ideas where i have gone wrong?

i will attach my bundles_config as well as my views (index and Layout)

please help. thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")*@
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>


--above is my Layout.cshtml
```

```js
above is an excerpt from my index view showing my table with an id(students).
```

```html
</table>
@section scripts
    {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#students").DataTable();

            $("#students").on("click", ".js-delete", function () {
                var button = $(this);
                bootbox.confirm("are you sure you want to delete this customer?", function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Students/delete/" + button.attr("data-student-id"),


                            method: "delete",
                            success: function () {
                                button.Parent("tr").remove();

                            }

                        });
                    }
                });


            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

```html
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace ContosoSite
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/lib").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootbox.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/datatables/jquery.datatables.js",
                        "~/Scripts/datatables/datatables.bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));


            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/datatables/css/datatables.bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}


above is my BundleConfig file
```

Comment: Can you add a snapshot for reference which is old grid design and what new you want?

Comment: did you check that the js and css render correctly?

Comment: @saineshwar i have added both images. one showing the way the grid is presently, the other showing what i expect it to be after applying the codes

Comment: @Mannan Bahelim i think so

Comment: Add these lines to the head section of the Layout page:   
 `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")`                                                             and move the line                            
 `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")` to the body like it is now.